# Monitoring Stackdriver using Prometheus

Tags: logging, prometheus, google-cloud-stackdriver

I am new to Prometheus. I am running a number of containers in Google cloud platform using Kubernetes. These containers send their logs onto Stackdriver. I would like to create metrics and chart using those logs in Prometheus. How could those logs which are on Stackdriver be scraped by Prometeus?
Any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

We are quite happy using [this exporter](https://github.com/frodenas/stackdriver_exporter) to ingest some of the StackDriver metrics to on of our Prometheus instances. Please note that this Exporter may need careful configuration, or else you might end up ingesting a huge number of metrics from SD. You should probably play around with the

```
STACKDRIVER_EXPORTER_MONITORING_METRICS_TYPE_PREFIXES
```

variable a bit.

Comment: Thank you very much. I am going to look into the exporter that you mentioned. For now I have one more general question. So one option is using an exporter to  ingest the StackDriver metrics to Prometheus instances. Are there any other options out there? and/or is it also possible/better/easier that we forget about Stackdriver and somehow manage to feed the logs directly from Kubernetes Containers (which are running on GKE) into Prometheus to create metrics/charts?

Comment: Prometheus is for metrics, not logs.

https://prometheus.io/docs/introduction/faq/#how-to-feed-logs-into-prometheus?